# コマンドライン上での命令の意味について

Tags: bash, sh

現在、macのTerminalから外部URLを参照し、  
ファイルが存在するかしないかの判定を行っています。

```
curl -I "http://hogehogehoge.com"
```

この後、コマンドラインから `echo $?` と入力し  
結果を出力していますが、`echo $?` はどういう意味をもっているのでしょうか？  
調べてみたのですが、説明に該当するページが存在しなかったため、  
この場をおかりいたしました。  
何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `echo $?` は直前に実行されたコマンドの `exit status`(整数値)を表示します(`$?` が `exit status`)。`man curl` を実行して、`EXIT CODES` を検索してみてください。

Comment: あぁ。そういうことですね。
ありがとうございます。
EXIT CODESをもとに判定のスクリプトを書いてみようと思います。

Comment: もしこの質問が解決した場合、その回答に対してチェック(承認)をつけて下さい。
そうすることで、後から見た人でもどの回答で解決したのかがわかりますし、お互いの信頼度が上昇します。[ヘルプ センター > 自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: `-f` か `--fail` オプションを付けないと，ファイルがなくても `EXIT CODES` の `22` ではなくて `0` が返ってくるような気がするので，付けた方がいいかもしれません．（少なくとも自分の環境ではそうでした）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo $?`は直前に実行したコマンドの終了コードを表示します。
正常に終了した場合`0`が返るようになっています。
`man curl`すればcurlがどのような場合に、どの終了コードを返すのか書かれているのでご一読ください。

Comment: はい。ありがとうございます。
初歩的な質問にもかかわらずありがとうございました。